# Nested List Forms ASP.NET MVC -- can't figure out how to code the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Apologies for how long this is...

This is the gist of what I am trying to do:

**Living Room Furniture**

- [QTY] Dining Table
- [QTY] Sofa

**Bedroom Furniture**

- [QTY] Nightstand
- [QTY] Armoire

I want to group pieces by category (stored in the database as one-to-many where each furniture piece has a category ID). I have been able to do something like this:

- [QTY] Dining Table
- [QTY] Sofa
- [QTY] Nightstand
- [QTY] Armoire

But once I try to arrange in categories it all goes to hell in a hand basket, and I CANNOT, FOR THE LIFE OF ME, Figure It Out. At all.

Here are my ViewModels:

```
public class FurnitureViewModel
{
    public int DeliveryID {get; set; }
    public List<FurnitureList> Categories { get; set; }

 }
public class FurnitureList
{
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public List<QuantityList> Furniture { get; set; }

}
public class QuantityList
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

My controller (which is definitely wrong and the source of the bulk of frustration):

```
    public IActionResult Furniture(int id) {
        FurniturePickupViewModel model = new FurnitureViewModel();
        var categories = context.FurnitureCategories.ToList();
        var furniture = new List<FurnitureList>();
        var quantityListItems = new List<QuantityList>();
        foreach (var cat in categories)
        {
            cat.Furniture = context.Furniture.Where(f => f.FurnitureCategoryID == cat.ID).ToList();
            foreach(var item in cat.Furniture)
            {
                quantityListItems.Add(new QuantityList
                {
                    ID = item.ID,
                    Name = item.Name,
                    Quantity = 0
                });
                furniture.Add(new FurnitureList
                {
                    CategoryID = cat.ID
                });
            }
        }
        model.Categories = furniture;
        return View(model);

    }
```

And the Views: 
Furniture.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Categories.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Categories[i])
}
}
```

FurnitureList.cshtml

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CategoryID)

<div class="block">
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Furniture.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(furn => furn.Furniture[i])
}
</div>
```

QuantityList.cshtml

```
@model Pickup.Models.DonationPickupViewModels.QuantityList
<div class="numbers-row">
@Html.TextBoxFor(furn => furn.Quantity, new { @class = "quantity" })
    @Html.LabelFor(furn => furn.Quantity, Model.Name, new { @class = "furn-item"                         

@Html.HiddenFor(furn => furn.ID)
```

I'm getting a NullReferenceException for Model.Furniture when I try to run this.

This was my controller for the not-categorized list that worked properly:

```
FurnitureViewModel model = new FurnitureViewModel();
        var furnitureItems = context.Furniture.ToList(); 
        var quantityListItems = new List<QuantityList>();
        foreach (var item in furnitureItems)
        {
            quantityListItems.Add(new QuantityList()
            {
                ID = item.ID,
                Name = item.Name,
                Quantity = 0
            });
        }
        model.FurnitureList = quantityListItems;
        return View(model);
```

I have tried looking this up. I've read about 4,567 articles on some variant of "nested lists ASP.NET MVC", and none of them speak enough to my situation to help. :'( What do I need to do to achieve this thing I want?

Thank you!

Comment: `NullReferenceException for Model.Furniture` Because you are not initializing `Model.Furniture` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code has lot of confusing names. You need to work on that.

`NullReferenceException for Model.Furniture` Because you are not initializing Model.Furniture in your code.

You are initializing `model` and set its property `Categories` to `furniture`.

You are adding new items to `furniture` list but you are not setting `Furniture` property of those new items. That's why you are getting NullReferenceException.

Consider changing your code to following.

```
public IActionResult Furniture(int id) {
FurniturePickupViewModel model = new FurnitureViewModel();
    var categories = context.FurnitureCategories.ToList();
    var furniture = new List<FurnitureList>();
    var quantityListItems = new List<QuantityList>();
    foreach (var cat in categories)
    {
        cat.Furniture = context.Furniture.Where(f => f.FurnitureCategoryID == cat.ID).ToList();
        var quantityListItems = new List<QuantityList>(); 
        foreach(var item in cat.Furniture)
        {
            quantityListItems.Add(new QuantityList
            {
                ID = item.ID,
                Name = item.Name,
                Quantity = 0
            });

        }
        furniture.Add(new FurnitureList
        {
            CategoryID = cat.ID,
            Furniture = quantityListItems
        });
    }
    model.Categories = furniture;
    return View(model);

}
```

This would resolve issue of `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Thank you so much! And I definitely will work on the naming, I admit I was in "^%$% just get it to work" mode, but I should get in the habit of good naming practices from the get go. Thanks again.